# Are there provably true statements which $\textit{don't}$ have a non-trivial proof by contradiction?

Tags: logic

... where a trivial proof by contradiction means effectively using a different proof technique to establish that the statement is true, and since you've assumed it's false, it's a contradiction.

Aside from that, the title pretty much says it all: do true mathematical statements exist which can only be proved with methods other than contradiction? It seems plausible that a statement that says anything worth saying would have logical implications which could eventually be made to show inconsistency, assuming the statement is provable one way or the other.

Comment: It seems your question is whether there is a P such that there is a proof q : (P -> false) -> false and each such q is in some suitable sense equal to some p^ where p : P and p^ : (P -> false) -> false is defined by p^ r = r p. If you use extensional equality, then the answer is trivially "yes", since false is a subsingleton. If you use intensional equality, then the situation could be more interesting. Intensional equality is the syntactic equality of normal forms. So your question is whether each such lambda term q reduces to something of the form p^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any of the "classical" mathematical systems that include the usual propositional logic,  you can (in principle) turn a "direct" proof into a proof by contradiction, essentially by reversing the steps.  Thus if your direct proof consists of statements $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n = P$, where each $S_i$ is either an axiom or follows by an axiom from its predecessors, you can start from $\neg P$ and deduce $\neg (S_1 \wedge S_2 \ldots \wedge S_{n-1})$, then $\neg (S_1 \wedge S_2 \ldots, \wedge S_{n-2})$, and so on until $\neg S1$ which contradicts an axiom.

However, in [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), where the law of the excluded middle is not included, this does not work, and in fact you can't e.g. prove that something
exists by proving that its non-existence would lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Any proof can be turned into a proof by contradiction: to prove $\phi$, you can always assume $\lnot\phi$, ignore that assumption until you have proved $\phi$ and then complete your proof by claiming that you have arrived at the contradiction $\phi \land \lnot\phi$. But this is a dumb way to go about proof: use proof by contradiction as a last resort.